# Adding multiple spaces in messagebar text using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I create a messagebar using this

```
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(iface.messageBar().createMessage( 'Hello World' ), Qgis.Info)
```

How can I add, say, 5 spaces between `Hello` and `World`?

I could use `'<pre>Hello     World</pre>'` to output exactly what I type but this changes the font of the messagebar. I would like to retain the same default font.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Qgis interface Message bar convert text into HTML for display. Multiples spaces are considered as only one in HTML, unless they are non-breaking spaces `&nbsp;`.

So, you can achieve your five blank spaces text with :

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("", f"Hello{'&nbsp;' * 5}World", Qgis.Info, -1)
```

**Explanation**

`'&nbsp;' * 5` gives `'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

`f"my string with curly brackets"` it's the new format way since Python 3.6

So with `f"Hello{'&nbsp;' * 5}World"`, I create this string `"Hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;World"` or <kbd>Hello     World</kbd>.

---

*See* :

- [PyQGIS documentation of QGIS message bar](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/gui/QgsMessageBar.html?highlight=qgsmessagebar#module-QgsMessageBar)
- [Python 3 new f-strings](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)